# Сжатие изоображений на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, img

Как сжимать изображение, кадрировать со стороны сервера и выводить их так... на подобии этого

```
https://image-cdn.hypb.st/https%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2018%2F08%2Fbest-new-tracks-august-10-2018-nicki-minaj-trippie-redd-bas-tirzah-0-2.jpg?464=&cbr=1&q=90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Класс `yii\imagine\Image`, предварительно поставив модуль php `GD` или `Imagick`.
2. Напрямую работать с библиотеками по работе с изображениями.